pd.Series.apply() converts Int32 to float when handling NA values in pandas
I am working with a pandas series whose dtype is Int32, and it includes some NA values. When applying the .apply() function to perform validations, I observe that the values are being converted to float, even when I explicitly reassert the dtype of the series before applying the function.
def _validate_and_transform_column(
    self,
    column_data: pd.Series,
    requirements: Dict,
    document_info: Document,
    language: LanguageTypeEnum,
) -> Tuple:

    processor: DataTypeProcessorBase = self.data_type_manager.get_processor(
        dtype=requirements["data_type"]
    )
    current_dtype = str(column_data.dtype) # Int32

    validation_response: pd.Series = column_data.apply(
        func=lambda x: processor.validator(value=x, requirements=requirements, language=language)
    )

I already tried but it doesn't work:
validation_response: pd.Series = column_data.astype("Int32").apply(
            func=lambda x: processor.validator(value=x, requirements=requirements, language=language)
        )

Question:
How can I prevent pd.Series.apply() from converting values from an Int32 series with NA to float during the function application? I am looking for a solution that allows me to treat these values as Int32 throughout the process without the presence of NA causing a conversion to float.

You can separate the NA values and non-NA values, apply the function only to the non-NA values,
and then combine them back.
def validate_or_return_na(x):
    if pd.isna(x):
        return pd.NA  # Keep as NA
    else:
        return processor.validator(value=x, requirements=requirements, language=language)

Create a custom function that explicitly handles the NA values and keeps the dtype intact.
validation_response: pd.Series = column_data.apply(validate_or_return_na)

validation_response = validation_response.astype("Int32")

